# Closing up blank space in JFreeChart bar chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am using `JFreeChart` and would like to display a bar chart of player's scores, with the score on the y-axis and the player's games grouped on the x-axis.

e.g.

```
String[] {Player name, score, game number}
Player 1, 10 , 1
Player 1, 12 , 2
Player 1, 15 , 3
Player 2, 11 , 1
Player 3, 18 , 1
```

Because the players do not have to play the same number of games, this results in a lot of blank space when the dataSet is created, as it tries to plot a bar for Player 2 & 3 games 2 & 3.

```
data.addValue(score, game number, player name);
```

Output: (the numbers dont quite match, this was just a quick test I knocked up)
[image: Note the blank space in player 1 game 3 and player 3 games 1 and 2]

Can anybody help me with how to close up this blank space? In theory player 1 could go on to play 100s of games with player 2 and 3 playing only a few, so it would look quite ridiculous!
I am new to JFreeChart so there is probably an obvious solution!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should change it to a stacked graph

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartStackedBarChartDemo1.htm

Comment: Thanks, but from looking at your link it seems that the stacked graph is more suited to displaying the total number of points scored across all games, whereas I would prefer to show each game side by side if possible.

Comment: don't know if this will help, but in some of my code, to prevent display I set the values to null, rather than just not including them.  If a line graph this allows two points not be joined if the data in between is missing

Comment: @user2310289, thanks for your comment. I tried setting the empty slots to null manually, but unfortunately the space was not closed up!

Comment: @ms813 Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690094/how-to-remove-top-white-space-from-pdf

Answer (score 16):

First Look at the Picture carefully
[image]

Here is some Explanation w.r.t Numbers.

1. setLowerMargin(Double margin).
2. setUpperMargin(Double margin).
3. setCategoryMargin(Double margin).
4. setItemMargin(Double margin).

Here is How you can use the methods in your chart

```
 CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 

 CategoryAxis axis = p.getDomainAxis();
 axis.setLowerMargin(0.1);
 axis.setUpperMargin(0.1);
 axis.setCategoryMargin(0.1);
 BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) p.getRenderer();
 renderer.setItemMargin(0.1);
```

You can set the value between 0.0 to 1.0 (example 0.1 means 10%)

Hope this Helps

(Update After your comment)
Well in this Case you should use **Layered Bar Chart**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for using JFreeChart in general. However it does not solve my specific problem. In your example, games player 0,1 and 2 have all played 3 games each. In my system, the players do not have to play the same amount of games, so it is not a case of the margins, rather that there is no data for some of the columns

Comment: Thanks again, I'l implement this for now. I would really like to use the grouped 3d bars though as I think they look a lot better and are easier to understand.