# How to remove space betwwen bars on a category in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a graph with two bars on each category value. How can we remove sapce beween bar on a category value. Space between bar of of with different category value should not be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I worked on this case using java customizer as follow:

```
public class BarChartCustomizerExIm implements JRChartCustomizer{

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

          BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
          barRenderer.setItemMargin(0);
   }
```

}

Put jar for this class in your class path and in customizer field in your ireport specify the classname.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own ChartCustomizer as follow:

```
public class CustomizeBarChart extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

    /**
     * Customizer for BarChart.
     *
     * @param chart the chart
     * @param jasperChart the jasperChart
     *
     * @see net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer#customize(org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart)
     */
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

        CategoryPlot categoryPlot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();

        //Spaces between bars
        renderer.setItemMargin(0.01);
    }
}
```

And add it as Customizer class in your chart preferences.

Comment: This will set sapce between all bars. But I want to remove space between bar on a category value. I have two bars for one category value.

Comment: it reduce spaces between bars, try to set 0.00 instead of 0.01

Comment: When I use this code `renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.03);` also in the class It again starts showing space between bars.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I have no idea. Also look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16738907/4580058

Comment: It did not work with 4 bars in graph. It works if there are more bars in graph.

Comment: It sounds strange, but try to set renderer.setItemMargin(-0.0); with minus before. If you use renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.03), then set -0.4

Comment: This also did not work. Negative sign reverses position of columns.