# What should I add to the series on the x axis so that it is time in the format mm: ss from the moment of strat? (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, time, jfreechart, stopwatch

I need to create real-time Graph from port,every second i would get double data.So i have to add on x axis time,but not time from computer,time from start scanning in format mm:ss .
I was trying in past just put int value and i++; it every second on x axis ,but since now i have to check getted data for reiteration it can't work, i need to add real stopwatch or Timer which shows current time since i start it
As I get -  I need to use TimeSeries insted of XYSeries,but only what i could get as result  - putting computer time on x axis

Comment: Use a `DateAxis`, which provides `setDateFormatOverride()`; see these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20DateAxis%20setDateFormatOverride) for typical usage.

Comment: Great thats.what i was looking for,thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JFreeChart X axis labels are going out of chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633234/jfreechart-x-axis-labels-are-going-out-of-chart-area)